# WP Custom CSS & JS still works after uninstall

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins

I used plugin simple CSS & JS on wp, it doubled script tag on page. Now if I make a change on editor it doesn't work because 2nd version(duplicate) form 1 day ago overrides it. How to get rid of this duplicate? Any way to clear all cache and data after this plugin?

Reinstall/uninstall plugin didn't work.

Comment: Do you use any cache plugin?

Comment: No, everything default